# How to put data in Ignite Cache from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, ignite

I managed several spark jobs to compute RDD and in the end, I would like to put some of these data in an Ignite Cache. Unfortunately, I have got an error :

```
Java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy
[info]  at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.equals(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:1715)
[info]  at scala.collection.mutable.FlatHashTable$class.findElemImpl(FlatHashTable.scala:131)
[info]  at scala.collection.mutable.FlatHashTable$class.containsElem(FlatHashTable.scala:124)
[info]  at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.containsElem(HashSet.scala:40)
[info]  at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.contains(HashSet.scala:57)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:87)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitExternalizable(SerializationDebugger.scala:142)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:104)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:206)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.find(SerializationDebugger.scala:67)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:400)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:371)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
[info]  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:370).........
```

So my question is how to put data coming from spark rdd in specific Ignite Cache, in our case, an Ignite Cache with 3rd persistence cache store implemented on Postgres?

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: I have also tried to use `IgniteRDD` `savePairs` but it is very slow.

Comment: I guess that you have some spark pair function that contains the cache proxy inside or something like that. That's why Stephen asked for the code sample. Please provide it. Also, I suggest taking a looks at this article, it contains the example for ignite Data Drames usage. It's pretty easier than using RDD. https://www.gridgain.com/resources/blog/how-debug-data-loading-spark-ignite